# A conditional probability problem where the next day depends on the last 3 days

Tags: probability, markov-chains, conditional-probability

For many years, Meteorologists have spent long visits (5 days) at the Bigtown.
They have observed that, for three consecutive days, if there are EXACTLY two sunny days, the next day is a sunny day*, while half of all the cloudy days are followed by another cloudy day. Assuming days are either cloudy or sunny, estimate how many days have been cloudy in their last ten visits. Visits are not necessarily following each other.

''half of all the cloudy days are followed by another cloudy day'' so $P(C\mid C)=50\%$

Is this possible? If not why not?

*i.e.
SSC -> S

SCS -> S

CSS -> S

where -> means followed by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: edited since the question was clarified.

First, we cannot ever have two or more consecutive sunny days. If we do, then the next cloudy day (which may not be for some time, but will certainly be preceded by two sunny days) must be followed by two sunny days (since SSC->S, SCS->S), and the same for the next cloudy day after that, and so on. In particular, every future cloudy day is followed by a sunny day, contradicting the assumption that $50\%$ of cloudy days are followed by sunny ones.

Second, we cannot ever have two sunny days separated by a single cloudy day, since then the next day will be sunny, contradicting the previous point.

Now we know that in between every two sunny days there are at least two cloudy days. These cloudy days must include one which is followed by a sunny day, and at least one which is followed by another cloudy day. Since these two things are equally common, we must have exactly two cloudy days between every two sunny days.

Thus the unique sequence satisfying these properties is ...SCCSCCSCC... in which exactly $2/3$ are cloudy.

Comment: The first case you describe seems to be bound to happen after a while, as soon in fact as there are 2 sunny days in 3 consecutive days. Indeed, sunny-sunny-cloudy for instance will be followed by a sunny day, and then the last three days will look like : sunny-cloudy-sunny, which again will be followed by a sunny day, and so on until there are no cloudy days anymore. So your answer cannot be complete, because after enough time has passed the meteorologist will only observe sunny days during their visits.

Comment: To be more clear, if you allow $X$ to take the value $1$ in your answer, then nothing prevents the configuration sunny-cloudy-sunny from happening, from which point onwards every day will be sunny. So $X$ has to be greater than $2$ for the trivial case to be avoided entirely.

Comment: @TheAmazingKitchen The first part of this question implies sunny-sunny-cloudy is followed by sunny with probability 1, while the second part of this question implies sunny-sunny-cloudy is followed by cloudy with probability 1/2. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @MatthewPilling The second part of the question doesn't imply that SSC will be followed by S with probability 1/2, only that a cloudy day about which you know nothing about has  probability 1/2 of being followed by a sunny day. So, for instance, a cloudy day which you know follows a sunny day presumably has a higher probability than 1/2 of being itself followed by  a sunny day, because as you pointed out SSC has probability 1 of being followed by S.

Comment: Got it, thank you.

Comment: The question does not say "for three consecutive days, if there are **at least** two sunny days, the next day is a sunny day", it says, or rather means, "for three consecutive days, if there are **exactly** two sunny days, the next day is a sunny day

Comment: Say the starting 3 days are SSC, then the next will be S and then the next will be S and the one after will be S but the one after that may or may not be S. SSCSSS. SSS does not have to follow with an S

Comment: @user716881 I highly recommend you edit your question to reflect this.

Comment: @user716881 With this said, I suspect that there isn't enough information to solve the problem. Indeed, you can assume without contradiction that SSS will be followed by S with probability 1, in which case (as I show in my now-deleted answer) after enough time has passed every day will be sunny. On the other hand, you can assume, also without contradiction, that SSS has probability 1 of being followed by C, in which case the sequence may end up being deterministic and looking like this after enough time has passed : CSSSCSSSCSSSC... Am I missing something ?

Comment: @TheAmazingKitchen I think you can solve the problem using Markov Chains. Consider the chain with $8$ states $$\{SSS,SSC,SCS,SCC,CSS,CSC,CCS,CCC\}$$ It's easy to see that the recurrent class
$$\{SSS,SSC,SCS,CSS\}$$

is absorbing. If we assume these weather patterns have been ongoing for quite a while, it's safe to say that, upon each visit to Bigtown, these Meteorologists enter this recurent class under some limiting distribution. This recurrent class has transition matrix \begin{pmatrix}p&1-p&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1\\ 1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix} where $p=P(SSS|SSS)$.

Comment: @user716881 thanks for the clarification - I've edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt to solve the problem:

Let's define the problem by a Markov chain, where a state of the chain is defined by the state of last (most recent) 3 consecutive days observed at any point in time (e.g., the state represented by CCC can transition to any of the two states, namely, itself, i.e., CCC and CCS). The state transition diagram will look like the following then

[image]

Notice that we don't have all the probabilities given to us (those are circled in the above figure), but some of them can be inferred and some of them can't be. For example, given, P(SCC|CCC)=1/2, so, consequently, P(CCS|CCC)=1-1/2=1/2. But we don't know either of P(SSS|SSS) and P(SSC|SSS), these are marked by x in the above figure.

For the sake of completeness (and simplicity), let's assume uniform probabilities for the unknown ones, e.g., let P(SSS|SSS) = P(SSC|SSS) = 1/2.

Then the Markov transition matrix becomes the one as shown below:

[image]

Now, the Markov chain being connected and aperiodic, by Perron-Frobenius theorem, it converges to stationary distribution in the long run.

Let's compute the stationary distribution, using the following R code with the Markov transition matrix $T$:

```
S <- T
for (i in 1:100)
  S <- S %*% T
```

[image]

Which shows that in the long run the Markov chain will be in the states CSS, SSC, SCS and SSS with probabilities 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 and 0.4, respectively. But the proportion of sunny days in these states are 2/3, 2/3, 2/3 and 1, respectively.

Hence, the expected number of sunny days will be = 0.2*2/3 + 0.2*2/3 + 0.2*2/3 + 0.4 = 0.8

Comment: I also thought that you couldn't find P(SSS|SSS), this question was based on a misinterpretation of the [real question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4028847/interpretation-of-a-question-on-probabilty).

Comment: According to you 8/10 of days are sunny but Especially Lime says it is 1/3

Answer (score 0):

For when you get a mathematical answer, the following simulations suggest that the answer is around 2.22.

```
nclo=0
for (k in 1:100) {
ncloud=0
for (j in 1:10000) {
  chain=rep(0, 10)
  for (i in 1:10) {
    if (i==3) {
      if (chain[1]+chain[2]==2) {
        chain=rep(1, 10)
        break
      }
    }
    if (i>3) {
      if (chain[i-1]+chain[i-2]+chain[i-3]>=2) {
        chain[i]=1
      }
    }
    if (runif(1)>.5) {
      chain[i]=1
    }
  }
  ncloud=ncloud+(10-sum(chain))
}
nclo=nclo+ncloud/10000
}
nclo=nclo/100
```

```
> nclo
[1] 2.221082
```