# Interpretation of a question on probabilty

Tags: probability, soft-question

I'm not sure this type of question is for this SE but I really need an answer possibly just as a comment.

''For many years, Basil and Rosemary have spent long weekends (4 days each) at the resort of Wetsun. They have observed that two sunny days in three are followed by another sunny day, while half of all the wet days are followed by another wet day. Days are either wet or sunny.''

I'm not sure if the question means:

1. "two sunny days in three [days]" i.e. of three days, if two are sunny, then the next day must be sunny, for example:

SSW->S

SWS->S

WSS->S

where -> means followed by.

2. "two sunny days in three [sunny days]" i.e. two thirds of sunny days are followed by as sunny day

Comment: Can you post the entire question?

Comment: @P.J. I'll send the introduction to the question but not the question itself.

Comment: If they speak about 2/3 of sunny days there should be at least 3 sunny days, and if they speak about 1/2 of wet days there should be at least 2 wet days. This does not sum to 4.

Comment: @user so do you think it would be interpretation (1)?

Comment: @user these 6 days (3 for sunny, 2 for wet) could be spread across visits. I think

Comment: @user716881 I did not note the final 's' in weekends. :)

Comment: English is not my native language but I would bet that the second interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the original text:

> They have observed that two sunny days in three are followed by another sunny day, while half of all the wet days are followed by another wet day. Days are either wet or sunny.

Here is my revision, staying as close to the original structure as possible:

> They have observed that, on average, every two out of three sunny days are followed by another sunny day, while on average, half of the time, a wet day is followed by another wet day.  Days are either wet or sunny.

I would state it like this:

- If on a given day it is sunny, the probability that the next day will also be sunny is $2/3$.
- If on a given day it is wet, the probability that the next day will also be wet is $1/2$.

The language is strangely phrased, but that is very clearly the intent.